# How to debug e2e tests with VS Code and type script

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have angular project generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

I'd like to debug e2e tests. 
As I undestood in order to do it I shoud compile tests from *.ts to *.js,
I found this info [here](http://www.bilyachat.com/2017/01/debug-protractor-typescript-tests-with.html) but it does not work for me.

Also I read [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#setting-up-vscode-for-debugging) article but it also does not work for me.

What I'm doing wrong? Please help me with it... I spent one week with no result...

My .vscode folder and 
**tasks.json** file

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "e2e-compile",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": [
                "run",
                "e2e-compile"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json** file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch e2e Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.debug.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "e2e-compile",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/out-tsc-e2e/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**protractor.config.debug.js** file

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './dist/out-tsc-e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  beforeLaunch: function() {

  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  }
};
```

Then I'm adding breakpoints and doing debug with F5, I'm waiting for pause but it just fails.
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related to the first line of your protractor configuration: `var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');`

Have a look at the console window output during the execution of the task:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:26978
[12:07:47] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:07:47] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:07:50] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: SpecReporter is not a constructor
    at onPrepare (c:\src\TableDojo\ClientApp\protractor.conf.debug.js:25:34)
```

There has been a breaking change in Jasmine (see [SpecReporter is not a constructor error when running protractor using angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001079/specreporter-is-not-a-constructor-error-when-running-protractor-using-angular-cl)). Try to change the aforementioned line with `var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;`

Works on my machine :-)